# Confusion about authentication in Azure Logic Apps

Tags: authentication, azure-logic-apps

I am building my own SaaS app and see Logic Apps as a nice way to extend it with functionality like getting files from other sources like Dropbox and Onedrive and also to save data directly to SalesForce or dynamics CRM.

All the examples I have seen so far just authenticate in the Logic Apps designer for these third party services but then it is specific accounts on Dropbox or Dynamics that are used.

What I need is for the currently logged in user in my app to be able to get files from his Dropbox account or push data to his Dynamics account. How would we achieve that? We can not hardcode that stuff anywhere.

Best regards